# Result of ps au | grep ssh different in Node.js (using spawn/pipe) vs shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, child-process

I'm playing around with node streams and child processes. So I want to emulate next shell command with pipes:

```
ps au | grep ssh
```

So I wrote next code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ps    = spawn('ps',   ['au']);
var grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

ps.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);

grep.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

Then I run it, but nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

P.S. - I know about:

```
require('child_process')
   .exec('ps au | grep ssh', function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
       ... 
   }).
```

I'm just playing around with Node.js, and I want to understand what's wrong with this example.

**Update 1:**
It appeared that with grep `bash` program works as expected, but with grep `ssh` there is no result. Although `ps au | grep ssh` gives me this result:

```
vagrant 11681 0.0 0.1 10464 916 pts/0 S+ 07:54 0:00 grep --color=auto ssh.
```

Comment: Your code works for me (except with `bash` instead of `ssh`). If you do `ps au | grep ssh` at your shell prompt, do you see output?

Comment: @mscdex Hmm, interesting. With `bash` command it works (result is the same as `ps au | grep bash`). With `ssh` there is no result. Although `ps au | grep ssh` give me result:

    `vagrant 11681 0.0 0.1 10464 916 pts/0 S+ 07:54 0:00 grep --color=auto ssh`.

Comment: Which userid are these nodejs scripts running under? Nobody or web user perhaps, instead of your login user?

Comment: I think there is some kind of timing issue because I can see the output sometimes but not always.

Comment: @Paul I call this script from console: `node pipe_example.js` using vagrant (virtual machine with OS Linux Ubuntu 14.04). So user - `vagrant`, user id - `1000`.

Comment: @DonghoYoo Yes, I'm also thinking so. But I don't understand why and  where? `pipe` command must push new data to grep.stdin, so we must have data on grep.stdout.

Comment: @DonghoYoo I tried wrap `ps.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin)` into process.nextTick. After this program begin works somtimes, but not always (as you already said)

Comment: No sure why you are surprised, `vagrant 11681 0.0 0.1 10464 916 pts/0 S+ 07:54 0:00 grep --color=auto ssh.` is the `grep ssh` process. If you do `ps au | grep ssh` it is up shell if it starts grep before `ps au` is launched, but this is not necessary as it also could buffer the result of `ps au` while starting `grep`, so whether you'll see the `grep ssh` of the pipe in the listing of `ps au` depends on the behavior of the used shell and the scheduling of the OS. The sample of `Dongho Yoo` might randomly not display `grep` in the process listing, but that it very unlikely

Comment: @t.niese As documentation for `streams`[http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable] says there are two mode `flowing` and `non-flowing`. In `non-flowing` mode all data is buffered, in `flowing` mode data is processed (emitting `data` event). You can switch to 'flowing' mode only by adding listener to `data` event, or by calling `stream.resume()` method, or by calling `pipe()` method. So there must be no differences which command (`ps` or `grep`) run first. Data from `ps` command must be buffered and passed to `grep` command after `pipe(grep.stdin)` call.

Comment: @t.niese Maybe I wrong. Feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `ps` it will list all currently running processes matching the passed options. Which might look for `ps au` something like this:

```
tniese  3251   0,0  0,0  2479028   3004 s000  S+    4:06am   0:00.03 -bash
root    4453   0,0  0,0  2452408    876 s004  R+    4:06pm   0:00.00 ps au
```

When you call `ps au | grep ssh` in the shell `grep` will filter that result to only show the lines containing `ssh`.

If the `grep` is launched by the shell before `ps` creates its listing then the output before the filtering would be:

```
tniese  3251   0,0  0,0  2479028   3004 s000  S+    4:06am   0:00.03 -bash
root    4453   0,0  0,0  2452408    876 s004  R+    4:06pm   0:00.00 ps au
tniese  4478   0,0  0,0  2441988    596 s000  R+    4:06pm   0:00.00 grep ssh
```

The `grep` process will match its own entry as it contains the passed parameters, so the filtered result would be:

```
tniese  4478   0,0  0,0  2441988    596 s000  R+    4:06pm   0:00.00 grep ssh
```

Lets look what is happening with your code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var ps    = spawn('ps',   ['au']);
var grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);

ps.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);
```

With spawn you tell the OS to start the process `ps`, `ps` does not need to wait to run until the output could be piped to anyplace but could start before that, it might only be forced to wait when it tries to write to the its output stream. Then your spawn `grep`, but at the time `grep` is launched `ps` might already created the process listing internally and cause of that it does not contain the `grep` process. The output of `ps` is then passed to grep. But as this output is missing `grep ssh` it won't show that line.

Wether `grep` will appear in your listing or not is highly OS dependent. Generally you should assume that it is random if it is listed or not. Or you would need to wait until `ps` exits and launch `grep` after that.

You need to always keep in mind that current OS have preemptive multitasking and that the scheduler  might pause node right after `spawn('ps',   ['au']);` and continue the process right after `ps` created/requested the listing.

I hope this explanation is a bit clearer then my comment.

Comment: Year. I've got your point. I think nobody can explain better, so mark you answer as accepted. But one last question: don't you think that node must buffer result data for `ps` command in stdout stream? Or at least have option to do so?

Comment: Create the [issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8757) for node. Let's core team decides correctness of such behavior.

Comment: @alexpods I assume that node or the OS itself already do buffering for the stdout of the _spawned_ process, but that does not really matte for your described _problem_. As long as `ps` is _spawnd_ before `grep`, it is more likely that `grep` won't appear in the listing then that it would appear, but this depends on the scheduler of the system what would happen. For the command `ps au | grep ssh` shell will most likely _spawn_ `grep` before it _spawns_ `ps`, and that's why you see `grep` as result in your shell. It is nothing wrong with both behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

I've spawned grep before ps and now it works well. I think it must be a timing issue. Try this.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var grep  = spawn('grep', ['ssh']);
var ps    = spawn('ps',   ['au']);

ps.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);

grep.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
  console.log(data.toString("utf8")); 
});
```

Comment: Year, it works! But I don't understand why? For me this is absolutely illogical. I'll wait a little - maybe someone knows something about it, maybe it's a feature, not a bug. If not - mark your answer as accepted and create issue in node github repository