# how to use grep command programmatically in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, grep

I am trying to Display only the **vmRSS** Attribute. When I run the command command

```
cat ./Status
```

I get alot of attributes and their corresponding values. What I am trying to do is to Display only the **vmRSS** programmatically. I can do it in the console as follows:

```
cat ./status | grep VmR
```

but how can I do it programmatically.

**my attempts**

```
const ls2 = spawn('cat', ['/proc/' + process.pid + '/status']);
```

Comment: JavaScript can't call console commands like that... Unless you're running node.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result of ps au | grep ssh different in Node.js (using spawn/pipe) vs shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979942/result-of-ps-au-grep-ssh-different-in-node-js-using-spawn-pipe-vs-shell)

Comment: @Cerbrus yes I am running node.js

Comment: @LetsamrIt: Okay, next time please add the tag :D

Comment: @LetsamrIt" You don't need to `cat` and `grep` later, you can do it in one shot `grep VmR status`

Comment: @Inian would you please provide an example in code

Answer (score 0):

Since *child_process* `spawn` launch a shell in a subprocess, I think you're better to do that within the current shell instead, with *child_process* `exec()` command.

Here is an example (thanks to @Inian):

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('grep VmR /proc/' + process.pid + '/status', (err, stdout) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  console.log(stdout)  // VmRSS:     13408 kB
})
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to spawn a shell to get that info, you could use *fs* to read the file, something like that:

```
const fs = require('fs');

let process_status = '/proc/' + process.pid + '/status';

fs.readFile(process_status, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)

  let lines = buf.split('\n')  // each line in an array
  let line = lines.filter(line => /VmRSS/.test(line))  // find interesting line
  let VmR = line[0].replace(/\t/g, '')  // clean output removing tabulation

  console.log(VmR)  // VmRSS:   13208 kB

})
```